# Facebook JavaScript SDK like button displayed sometimes in Japanese and sometimes in Spanish when I specify en_US

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, xfbml

When I use the following:

```
//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3
```

I get: いいね！3

Or sometimes: Me gusta 3

Here is Facebook's documentation on setting the language:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/#language

Has anyone else run into this? Is there something else that is overridding the language?

Answer (score 0):

I am running into this as well - no luck finding a solution so far. Started a few days ago..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).